# Can you align items from display() in a row in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way I can use display() but instead of each display printing under each other, align them to display in one row?

```
display(data.groupby("Name").size())
display(data.groupby("Year").size())
```

For example altering this to show two tables side by side instead of

```
    Name
Mike    6324
George  822
dtype: int64

    Year
2000    23
1999    33
1998    44
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

The visual styling of dataframes can be amended.

Following small snippet

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display_html

data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'George', 'George'],
                     'Year': [2000, 2000, 2001, 2000, 1999]
                    })

name_series = data.groupby("Name").size()
year_series = data.groupby("Year").size()

name_series.name = ''
year_series.name = ''

name_dataframe = name_series.to_frame()
year_dataframe = year_series.to_frame()

name_styler = name_dataframe.style.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")
year_styler = year_dataframe.style.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")

display_html(name_styler.render() + year_styler.render(), raw = True)
```

will be rendered in Jupyter as

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to title the entire table?

Comment: @chung Those are actually two HTML tables. There is no simple way to place a title across both. You might [set a caption](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_caption.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_caption) for one/both of them. e.g. `...set_table_attributes(...).set_caption("the caption")`.

Answer (score 0):

How to display full output in Jupyter, not only last result?

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```